# jenkins Declarative pipeline, condition for using specific nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

My non working pipeline ( declarative):

```
def parentWorkspace = "${params.WS}"   // comes from upsteam job
def parentNode = "${params.NODENAME}"  // comes from upsteam job

pipeline {  
    agent none
    stages {
    
    stage("checkout source and run tests") {
        steps{
         script {  
          if(parentWorkspace != "null") 
          {  
           agent {
            node{
             customWorkspace "${parentWorkspace} "
             label "${parentNode} "
            } 
           }
        else {
         agent {
            label 'linuxVM'
           }
            
         }
      }
     steps {
            git url: gitLocation, branch: branchName, poll: false
            sh "mvn test ..." 
       }
   }
 }
```

}

if the "parentworkspace" varibale is not null, use custom workspace with provided parentworkspace path and node label. Otherwise use default workspace and node with label "linux" .  is it possible  ?

tried few options couldn't really make it work. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the if condition outside your pipeline block like below:

```html
def parentWorkspace = "${params.WS}"   
def parentNode = "${params.NODENAME}"  
script {
    if(parentWorkspace != "null") {
        label "${parentNode} "
    }
    else {
        label 'linuxVM'
    }
}
pipeline {
  //your pipeline code
}
```

For allocation of workspace use ws("${params.WS}")

Reply back if this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Hi, Not sure , if it works as expected.   i want to use same workspace as in  "node_name".     
still  tried as you said, but no luck                    
 
in  start,     pipeline {  agent { node 'xxx' }     what is the node name i can give ? where  ws("${params.WS}")  i can define ?    If the upstream job pass the parameters, workspace and node name i have to run the job in the same node and use the same workspace, that's my goal.  otherwise job can run normally, with its own workspace and any node of given label. Can you make some small working script in pipleine code  example: sh 'pwd' ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this works perfect for me for the custom workspace issue

```
agent {
   label "whatever"
   customWorkspace params.WS
}
```

If params.WS is null or empty string, you get the original workspace since the value used for customWorkspace can be a relative path with respect to the original workspace.